# One Div in the center, another div to the right of it

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is very simple stuff, but I hate CSS and it's just not playing ball for me.

Here's an illustration of my site layout:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ueJrtCd.jpg]

The aim is to have the flash centered, and the div containing an ad slightly to the right. Obviously it's important that I can easily set the gap between the flash and the ad.

At the moment I'm using a container div, shown in dotted blue, with the flash centered inside it and the ad display: inline-block, float:right. It works, but the problem is if the browser width is reduced to the point where it is smaller than the dotted blue box, the empty space on its left is preserved and the flash and ad are pushed to the right and cut off. I'd like the opposite to happen, the ad is preserved and the left side of the container is cut off.

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You really should share you problematic code, but from what I understand, you can try something like:

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flash, .ad {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

While the HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flash"></div>
  <div class="ad"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not going to work. `.flash` will not be centered in the middle of the page.

Comment: @hungerstar Right, I forgot he added a `.container` of his own. I think my edit will fix that.

Comment: It won't, `margin: 0 auto;` does not work without a width being set. Even then, you'll get the same result.

Comment: It's "centered" but not centered, http://jsfiddle.net/wL3wzt8j/. `.flash` + `.ad` together are centered but `.flash` itself is not centered. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah I understand. This can be simply solved by adding a `margin-left` to flash with the width of `.ad`, [like so.](http://jsfiddle.net/ct2u99nL/2/)

Comment: Unfortunately that does not do what the OP wants. The margin will remain at smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

use below code 
html code is.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="left">
         <p>flash</p>      
    </div>
     <div id="right">
         <p> advertise</p>        
    </div>
</div>
```

and css code is

```
       #parent{
    border:1px solid #CC0000;
    overflow:hidden;
     margin:0 auto;
}
#parent div{
    float:left;

}
#left{
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:150px;
    width:300px;
    height:250px;
}
#right{
     border:3px solid #000;
 width:200px;
    height:250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the others answers and I think I've found a solution.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 0;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.flash, .ad {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.flash {
    min-width: 300px;
    margin-left: 110px; //this has to be total width of .ad 
}

.ad {
    min-width: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flash"></div><!--
  --><div class="ad"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wL3wzt8j/2/

Since this code will not work well with what you're trying to do (on screens that are smaller than the container), here's another fiddle, that involves absolute positioning:

http://jsfiddle.net/wL3wzt8j/3/

Comment: Unfortunately that does not do what the OP wants. The margin will remain at smaller resolutions.

Comment: @hugestar I'm trying to find just a non-absolute positioning solution. The only other solution I see is use absolute positioning and float right in the ad, with position relative set for z-index higher than the flash div

Comment: That's fine and all but these solutions do not meet the OPs requirements.

Comment: @hungerstar I think the last one is the closest to his requirements, but OP is really not helping much, since he's saying anything about our answers.

Comment: My apologies for not responding, but you're right hungerstar, none of the solutions have quite hit my requirement yet. I guess it's not as simple as I thought it might be. The goal is that the flash is centered so that it lines up nicely with all the other elements on the page, and then has the ad to the right of it. But if the browser width is too small for the ad to sit there, the ad and the flash need to be pushed to the left and use up the space there. In my current code the left space is preserved and the ad goes off the edge. In the other solution here, the ad jumps below the flash.

Comment: Well, what kind of technologies you're allowed to use? CSS3? Maybe even javascript could solve this problem. I'm not the best out there, so sometimes I end up using any hacky/tricks I found out for my solution, even if those solutions are not the best.